# Can´t access child theme´s scripts dependencies found in parent

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-dependencies

I´ve been struggling with this for nearly a month now and still couldn´t find anything at all on how to do this! Not here, not in Quora, not through many different advanced Google search queries...

Here it is:

The **parent theme** has only **one script file** `main.min.js`. It contains all the scripts and libraries being used by it, including `jQuery`, `Select2`, `Parsley` and `Slick`, to name a few.

How do I go about **making my own scripts use one or more of these libraries as their dependencies in the child theme**?

The immediatelly obvious approach is to declare the parent theme `main.min.js` as the dependency when enqueueing my own scripts in the child´s `functions.php` and make sure my scripts fire after the dependency has been loaded on the page.

I´ve done that, yet, it doesn´t work. My scripts cannot access their dependencies.

The only alternative I can think of is enqueueing all these libraries separately in the child theme, as if the parent didn´t have them. Which is clearly a horrible thing to do, as the parent theme will load these libraries in its main js file too!

So there must be a way to do this by using the **already provided libraries** in the parent.

Had the parent theme enqueued the libraries separately this would be easy. I guess the main issue here is that all scripts and libraries are included in one single js file.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Got any code we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent theme bundles all vendor scripts in one file, you can't require/enqueue them separately. From WP's point of view, they are one single resource/dependency.

Look into any page's source-code or use a plugin (such as "debug this") to get the script's register name so you could specify it as dependency. In your case it could be `{parentThemeSlug}-main`. It's not the file name, but the register name which needs to be specified in the dependencies array (i.e. `jquery.min.js` is `jquery`). I usually look it up in parent theme by finding the register/enqueue function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57369/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-gheorghiu-cant-access-child-themes-scripts-depe).

Comment: It's not exactly like we socialized. I tried to help out and some of it could have been useful to others, too. Well, I guess you know better. Happy coding, @toscho

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of providing an answer in case people get here and don´t go through the comments, this is the reason why I had this issue:

The parent theme developers use **browserify to create the final bundle** for the theme. And the way browserify works, **such bundle is completely hidden from the global scope.**

So even though it has all the libraries I need in it, I can´t access them outside their original environment.

One can argue that, in such case, this theme is not meant to be used as a parent theme. Which is a valid input but, as I want/need to keep going, that leaves me 3 options:

1- **Create redundance** and code bloat by having the same libraries in my child theme separately. (not really an option, is it?)

2- **Add to the parent theme** and make and extra effort to keep things tidy in order to be able to have the mods clean cut for next theme releases, like [Andrei](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/45169/andrei-gheorghiu) kindly suggested in the comments. (kindda risky though as, not only I´m not yet an expert theme developer, it´d also require extraordinary attention, which leaves room for a lot of possible issues. Who knows what could happen).

3- **Copy, modify and recompile parent theme source files** then overwrite the final bundle through the child theme by keeping the same file name/handle as the original since the child´s `functions.php` will load first.

The latter seems the **most practical and cleanest option**, so I´ll stick to it and see how it goes.

Thanks to [Andrei](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/45169/andrei-gheorghiu) once again for all his input throughtout this.